# nodejs sessionStore: api?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Where do I find api information about req.sessionStore?

I was checking out a library applying:

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'req', { value: req });
 this.req.sessionStore.set(this.id, this, fn || function(){});
```

https://github.com/btd/connect-session/blob/master/lib/session/session.js#L24

But haven't been successful finding the api thusfar.
Alternative documentation about request.sessionStore is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer** all the store methods can be obtained here:
https://github.com/expressjs/session#session-store-implementation

**Long Answer**
It took 3 steps to debug this

First where is the req.sessionstore coming from?

https://github.com/btd/connect-session/blob/master/lib/session.js#L78

```
// expose store
req.sessionStore = store;
```

Second, what is the store, it can be passed via options while creating the session or it will pick from MemoryStore

https://github.com/btd/connect-session/blob/master/lib/session.js#L46

```
store = options.store || new MemoryStore
```

Third, MemoryStore is where we have all the setter methods

https://github.com/btd/connect-session/blob/master/lib/session/memory.js#L67

```
MemoryStore.prototype.set
```

Since connect and express share similar middlewares, for other compatible sessionstores instead of default MemoryStore, you can refer to

https://github.com/expressjs/session#compatible-session-stores